# LayoutInflater throws stackoverflow exception when attached to root in android

Tags: java, android, listview, exception

I am making an activity with three tabs. Each of the tabs should have a list view inside them.

my fragments looks like this

```
public class fragment1 extends Fragment {


public fragment1(){

}

static Context context;
static LayoutInflater inflater;

public void setDepends(Context context, LayoutInflater inflater){
    this.context = context;
    this.inflater = inflater;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guideline_fragment1, container, false);
    //some code

    return rootView;
}
```

But list view is not scrolling and whenever i try to write

`final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.guideline_fragment1, container, true);`

it throws stackoverflow exception

here is my mainactivity xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">
</LinearLayout>
```

and my fragment xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/kid_guideline_refresh_layout"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/guideline_kids_listview"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:fillViewport="true"></ListView>
</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah, don't do that. The `View` will be added to the hierarchy for you. You don't want to attach it.

Comment: only problem is that my listview is not scrolling and niether the swipe to refresh layout is working

Comment: Are you sure you have enough items in your list for the `ListView` to be scrollable? That is, is the total height of the list items taller than the `ListView`?

Comment: yes it is. I am doing that programmatically

Comment: How are you handling the `Fragment`s, exactly? I mean, how are you creating and displaying them? The `Activity` layout you've posted has no ID for the `LinearLayout`, and that `setDepends()` method in your `Fragment` class seems odd, and unnecessary.

Comment: I have created a custom viewPager Adapter and added the fragments to it and then written this line tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

Comment: Well, it sounds like a problem with your layout, if everything else is working, but there's more to it than just the `LinearLayout` you've posted.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?